# Alamofire multi parameters dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3, alamofire

Hi i am trying to give to alamofire parameters called "addons" that are in array...array can contain 3 or X items. I am trying to use FOR cycle to ad dictionary to another another one set of items, but...it only shows the last one...that seems it override the previous one. I tried everything I know...Even try to use SwiftyJSON framework....but alamofire only take pure dictionary type.

```
    let itemsArr = ["Skirts", "Coat", "Shirt"]
    let priceArr = ["7.00", "7.00", "2.90"]
    let quantityArr = ["2", "5", "1"]

    let personalInfo: [String : Any] = [
        "phone" : phone,
        "notes" : descNote
    ]

    var para: [String: Any] = [
        "pieces" : pieces,
        "personal_info" : personalInfo,
        "payment_method" : paymentMethod
    ]

    for i in 0..<itemsArr.count {
        let addons: [String: Any] = [
            "name":itemsArr[i],
            "price":priceArr[i],
            "quantity":quantityArr[i]
        ]
        print(addons)
        para["addons"] = addons
    }
```

well I need something like this

```
{
  "pieces": 12,
  "personal_info": {
    "phone": "+420783199102",
    "notes": "Plz be fast, I need to play Game of War"
  },
  "payment_method": "cod",
  "addons": [
    {
      "name": "Select day Tue",
      "price": 3.5,
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Select day Thu",
      "price": 3.5,
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in loop you are overwriting variable every single iteration with single result. That's why only last one is left for you.
What you should do is:

```
//create an array to store the addons outside of the loop
var addons: [[String: Any]] = []
for i in 0..<itemsArr.count {
    let addon: [String: Any] = [
        "name":itemsArr[i],
        "price":priceArr[i],
        "quantity":quantityArr[i]
    ]
    //append a single addon to our array prepared before the loop
    addons.append(addon)
}
//once we gathered all addons, append results to `para` dictionary
para["addons"] = addons
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying something with dictionary in array too, but syntax was no good so I could not append collection. Anyway you saved me from a big headache. ;-)